# How to remove baml from WPF assembly?

Tags: wpf, reflection, .net-assembly, mono.cecil, baml

Using the merged resource dictionaries degrade application performance. In my assembly I often need to use merged resource dictionaries. I want to combine resources in one dictionary, and delete the original baml. I can't set Build Action to None (instead of Page), because in this case I lose some functionality (e.g., no syntax highlighting by resharper). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

At *run-time* your application still need to read the linked BAML resources files, for this reason you can't remove BAML from your assembly.

For example:

You merge the following resource dictionaries

- `dictionary1.xaml`
- `dictionary2.xaml`

in `merged.xaml`.

You cannot simply remove the compiled XAML (BAML - `dictionary1.baml` and `dictionary2.baml`), because, as I wrote, at *run-time* you still need these resources.

But, anyway, you could literally copy the content of your XAML resources on `merged.xaml`, in this way you will have only `merged.baml` (after the compiler has generated it in your assembly resource part).

Comment: I already copy the content from my dictionaries to merged.xml file, but I don't want delete dictionary1.xaml and dictionary2.xaml files, but I need to it, because otherwise compiler will generate dictionary1.baml and dictionary2.baml. Can I delete dictionary1.baml and dictionary2.baml manually?

Comment: Yes, you can delete these files, as you can delete any other files not protected or used by another process (if you use VS you can usually find them under `obj` directory), **but**, as I wrote, these files are needed for your application.

Comment: No, these files no needed for my application. merged.xaml already contains all data of dictionary1.xaml and dictionary2.xaml, because I COPY data from dictionary1.xaml and dictionary2.xaml to merged.xaml. I DON'T use ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary property.

Comment: Thus remove the dictionaries if you want or at most set their build action to `None`.

Comment: I don't want set Build Action to None (instead of Page), because in this case I lose some functionality (e.g., no syntax highlighting by Resharper).